# nested for each loop to insert value which in array without duplication and loop start from first

Tags: javascript

Example 
**If my values are in array like this**

```
var myPlaces = ["a", "b", "c"];
var friendPlaces = ["d", "0", "e"];

for(var i = 0; i < myPlaces.length; i++) {
   console.log(myPlaces[i]);

   for(var j = 0; j < friendPlaces.length; j++) {
      if (myPlaces[i] == friendPlaces[i]) {
          console.log(myPlaces[i]);
      };
```

**I need answer as 
(a,d)(b,0)(c,e) as three result** but it gives count more than 3
help me to modify **my current answer** (a,d) (d,a) (d,b) (d,c) then (b,o)

Comment: please add the wamted result.

Comment: please add a few more clarifications.

Comment: 1st the current output is `a  b  c`, 2nd it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: nested for each loop is used in asp .net also so i included the .net tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (*Assuming your `input arrays` are of same `length` with fixed count of arrays- i.e. `2` in your case*).

If you use `map` on `myPlaces` then 1st parameter is current value of `myPlaces` in loop and the 2nd parameter is `index` of that element in array. So you can match current element in `myPlaces` with elements from `friendPlaces` array with the same index using this index.

```js
var myPlaces = ["a", "b", "c"];
var friendPlaces = ["d", "0", "e"];
var result = myPlaces.map((e, i) => "("+e +","+ friendPlaces[i]+")");
console.log(result);
```